# Запятые при «и(,) хотя... однако»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, спп

> Марья взяла письмо(1) и(2) хотя едва умела читать(3) однако ж смотрела на него(4) и слезы лились из глаз ее.

Где здесь нужны запятые **и почему**? Будьте добры, дайте ссылки на правила.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***(1)Марья взяла письмо,  и (2) хотя (она) едва умела читать,  однако ж смотрела на него, и (3) слезы лились из глаз ее.***

**1) Грамматический анализ**

Сложное предложение с сочинительной союзной связью, но два союза И не являются повторяющимися. Второй союз И соединяет предложения 2 и 3, а первый союз И соединяет предложение 1 и предложения 2 и 3.

Предложение 2 **осложнено однородными сказуемыми,** связанными двойным союзом ХОТЯ...ОДНАКО (НО). Сравнить: *Она хотя едва умела читать, но смотрела на него.*

**2) Знаки препинания**

Хотя три первых сказуемых относятся к одному субъекту действия, **их нельзя считать однородными.** Однородны только второе и третье сказуемое в предложении 2, так как они составляют **пару (закрытый ряд)**.

Поэтому вторая часть выделяется как отдельное неполное предложение 2 с пропущенным подлежащим ***она***.

**Запятая 1** ставится между предложением 1 и 2, **запятая 2** не ставится перед первой частью двойного союза, **запятая 3** ставится перед второй частью двойного союза, **запятая 4** ставится перед предложением 3.

Противительный союз ОДНАКО не может быть **общим элементом** для предложений 2 и 3 согласно правилу Розенталя:

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

2. **Противительный союз,** после которого или перед которым находятся два соединенных союзом и простых предложения, общим элементом не является, поэтому запятая перед и ставится: *Ибрагим был бы очень рад избавиться, но ассамблея была дело должностное, и государь строго требовал присутствия своих приближённых* (П.);

Answer (score 4):

*Марья взяла письмо, и хотя едва умела читать, однако ж смотрела на него, и слезы лились из глаз её.*

Между союзом *И* и союзом *ХОТЯ* не ставится запятая.

Из Грамоты (http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_188): Если в сложном предложении рядом оказались сочинительный и подчинительный союзы (*И* и *ХОТЯ*, *И* и *КАК* и др.), то нужно выяснить, нет ли после придаточной части соотносительных слов *ТО*, *ТАК* или еще одного сочинительного союза (*А*, *НО*, *ОДНАКО* и др.). Запятая ставится только тогда, когда эти слова после придаточной части отсутствуют.

> Женщина все говорила и говорила о своих несчастьях, и хотя слова ее
>   были привычными для Сабурова, но от них вдруг защемило сердце.

Comment: В примере Грамоты двойной союз соединяет простые предложения в составе сложного, а в заданном предложении он соединяет однородные члены. Разница существенная.

Comment: Из Грамоты слова не выкинешь.

Comment: Из Грамоты - да.